# Linux in Oracle VirtualBox VMs runs slow and black screens on MacBook Pro

Tags: catalina, unix, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm trying to install a Linux Virtual Machine in Oracle VirtualBox on MacBook Pro 2019 on Catalina, but I am having issues. Ubuntu goes black screen during installation, usually happens when creating user account or during the installation process itself. Other, more lightweight distributions are fine until I actually start to use them, they become extremely sluggish to a point where it takes a couple of seconds to process any input.

I've used the default setting, tried to give it more RAM and more CPU threads. Any other settings I should look out for?

Comment: What version of VB?

Comment: 6.1.2 @Tetsujin

Comment: hmm, OK - should be new enough, though I'd give 6.1.4 a try, just in case

Comment: Managed to install Ubuntu 19.04 with 6.1.4, but the extreme lag in some applications still persists, namely, while using SDL library to get inputs and draw